# Codeigniter can't fetch all data from database table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am fetching data from mysql database table in codeigniter using following code

```
 $result = $this->db->get("shipping");
 $data =  $result->result_array();
```

But returns no data.

When I apply the limit as

```
$this->db->get("shipping",1,30)
```

The code works.

But I want to fetch all result and not by limiting it.
Could anyone please let me know how do I resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: add charset=utf8 in your connection. maybe because you have special character in your database. like ñ.

Comment: It is already set as char_set=utf8 @BarclickFloresVelasquez .

Comment: That code should work. I actually tested it just to make sure with some made up data. Can you post the actual data in the database if it is not too big or confidential or something? Preferably as an SQL dump.

Comment: @azbatuk the database is having 90 columns and 90 rows currently.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using query rather than get?

```
     $sql = "
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            shipping
    ";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $data = $query->result();
```

Comment: yea used this approach too.

Comment: It works when I limit the result or query "select top 30 * from shipping" but when I query "select * from shipping it won't work".

Answer (score 0):

You have not put a return

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

```
// This will get every result from shipping
public function somefunction() {
  $result = $this->db->get("shipping");
  return $result->result_array();
}
```

Controller function

```
public function somecontrollerfunction() {

    $this->load->model('some_model');

    $data['shipping'] = array();

    $data['shipping'] = $this->some_model->somefunction();

    // var_dump($data['shipping']);

    $this->load->view('your_view', $data);

}
```

Comment: I was returning the result before.